# IOS Google Map SDK and Parse Bitcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, parse-platform

In Project Only Google Map SDK need [Enable Bitcode = NO],

In Project Only Parse need [Enable Bitcode = YES].

By the way, I want create Project with Google Map SDK and Parse.

How can I Setting Bitcode?

I can't Run my App now...

Comment: I solved this problem, I remove Facebook, Twiter parse framework

Comment: and add  libstdc++6.tbd. by the way, this problem was about -Objc linker!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcode is not currently required for iOS apps. You can set `Enable Bitcode = NO` at any point for iOS.